# Custom training TF Object Detection Model Evaluation

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api, tensorflow-model-garden

I would appreciate a little help on some evaluation results that I have got from a Custom trained model. I'm working with the SSD MobileNet v2 320x320 from http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

I have 12 classes for my objects that I want to detect and classify annotated with the PASCAL VOC format (one XML file per image).
Moreover, I did 2 different training with different random seeds. So this issue is not only for one training.
So I'm evaluating these models according to the official TF-Object-Detection GitHub https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md

I'm using 2 metrics :

- coco_detection_metrics : this one gives general mean Average Precision (mAP) @IoU=0.5, @IoU=0.75, @IoU0,5:.05:0.95 and **good global results**.

The problematic metric is the following by category, so for each class :

- pascal_voc_detection_metrics with the following configuration :

```
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "pascal_voc_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 2092  # number of test images
}
```

On both training, my most present class (about 2-3k images over 10k) has a very low precision near 0, like 10^-3 and I really don't know why because all the other categories are above 75-80% of precision.

Tensorboard is showing graphs with alphabetical order, so I annotated my **2nd picture** with classes numbers.
Let's see metrics for the **first training** :
[1st_training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfrEU.png)

Let me show you more detailled metrics curves for the **second training** :
[2nd_training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKHJl.png)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Update : I did a short training (5000 steps only instead of 50000) without the problematic class that has a precision really near 0.
The thing that changed on COCO metrics is that the "small" size category is now undefined, so I got a problem with small objects.

Comment: Then I did this training on 11 classes without the 1st one that was a problem in metrics. After that, the major class now is the class 2 but it has a really near 0% precision like the class 1 before ...